How can I visualize hierarchy chart leaderboard in C++?
Leaderboard Examples
Can anyone help me on how to make a hierarchy chart type of leaderboard in C++ like in the example given?
I've tried using vector, but it seems like the results is not neat/clean. Can anyone help me how to add the lines like this:
                                    Rank1
                                      |
               +----------------------+-----------------------+
            Rank2                                            Rank3
              |                                               |
   +----------+----------+                           +--------+--------+
Rank4                   Rank5                      Rank6              Rank7

and so on until Rank31.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// Function to print a row of winners
void printRow(const vector<string>& row, int totalWidth) {
    int elements = row.size();
    int spaceBetween = (totalWidth - elements) / (elements + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < elements; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < spaceBetween; ++j)
            cout << " ";
        cout << row[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
}

// Function to print the winners' chart
void printWinnersChart() {
    vector<vector<string>> winnersChart = {
        {"Bob"},
        {"Alice", "Charlie"},
        {"David", "Eve", "Frank", "Grace"},
        {"Henry", "Isabella", "Jack", "Kate", "Liam", "Mia", "Noah", "Olivia"},
        {"Penelope", "Quinn", "Ryan", "Sophia", "Thomas", "Uma", "Victoria", "William", "Xavier", "Yara", "Zoe", "Adam", "Bella", "Caleb", "Diana", "Ethan"}
    };

    int totalWidth = 80;

    for (const auto& row : winnersChart) {
        printRow(row, totalWidth);
    }
}

int main() {
    cout << "Figure 2: Sample of the winners' chart" << endl;
    printWinnersChart();

    //wait for the user to press enter to exit terminal
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}



First, take a piece of paper and write an algorithm to generate desired user-readable text output. Then I would say it will be easier to first generate all rows of the output, and print it in the end, rather than doing it on the fly.

Draw a box around every node in your tree. You will see that the size of each box is the sum of the size of the child nodes plus a bit for the root node in that box. The label of the root node should be centered over the box it contains. If you perform this calculation you will end up with the correct positions of every node in the tree.

imho you first need to realize that you are mixing up two separate concerns here. One is how to represent the data internally, the other is how to visualize it. A vector can be ok for the internal representation. Its not the best, but it can be used. But the drawing on the screen is about finding the right width and counting number of characters to be printed, and should not be affected by the choice of how you store the data.

Note that "Penelope Quinn Ryan Sophia Thomas Uma Victoria William Xavier Yara Zoe Adam Bella Caleb Diana Ethan" is 99 characters so these names can not physically fit side-by-side with  totalWidth = 80 constraint.
